# How to set or condition in filtering multiple columns using Angular pipe

Tags: angularjs, angular-pipe

I am using the reference from [here](https://offering.solutions/blog/articles/2016/11/21/how-to-implement-a-table-filter-in-angular-2/) and able to achieve the results.

Here is my table:
[image: Table]

When I type an ID, I am able to see results. But when I enter a quantity/date, it does not show any results.

I want to be able to filter by either ID, Quantity or Date. Is there any way I can do it?

Here is my current code:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="searchString" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="searchString">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let bot of bots | filter : searchString;">
            <td>{{bot.id}}</td>
            <td>{{bot.Qty}}</td>
            <td>{{bot.Date}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

filter.pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filter',
    pure: false
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], term): any {
        console.log('term', term);

        return term 
            ? items.filter(item => item.title.indexOf(term) !== -1)
            : items;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<tr *ngFor="let bot of bots | filter : searchString;">
```

just remove this `: 'id'` and it will work on all the fields!

EDIT1:

Please update your filter as per this

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filter',
    pure: false
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[], term): any {
        console.log('term', term);

        return term 
            ? items.filter(item => item.title.indexOf(term) !== -1)
            : items;
    }
}
```

just to update this line cause problem for you

```
if (!field || !value) {
            return items;
        }
```

Comment: Hi, I have changed accordingly but still does not work! I updated the code snippet, can you see if there is anything not done correctly? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ..

```html
<tr ng-repeat="let bot of bots | filter : 'id' : searchString;" | filter:ageFilter">

$scope.ageFilter = function (bot) {
    return (bot.age > $scope.min_age && player.age < $scope.max_age);
}
```